# How do you pass in a database variable generated from a previous web page?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a database of customers, and I am trying to display the most recently added customer data on a separate webpage. The customer fills out their info on a submission page, and when they click submit, they are redirected to another page that displays the info they just entered:

```
<div class = "form-group">
<label id = "firstnamelabel">@Customer.FirstName</label>
<label id = "lastnamelabel">@Customer.LastName</label>
//etc...
</div>
```

However, Visual Studio intellisense says Customer doesn't exist in the current context. I feel like I'm just missing a way to reference the entry from the submission page, but I could be really far off. Is there another way I should be going about this?
I've also tried adding the script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var CustomerIndex = model.Customer.Count - 1;
        FirstName = model.Customer[CustomerIndex].FirstName;
        document.getElementById('firstnamelabel').innerHTML = FirstName;
    });
</script>
```

I've looked through other users' questions, but I'm not seeing anyone who also tried to pull the last entry from a database to display on a separate webpage.
I'm a novice, so I'm sorry if this seems like a basic question on html; I appreciate any help!
(I'm using ASP.NET Core Web App Razor Pages)

**EDIT**
Here's what I am using to generate the data.
Create.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-8 ">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <h4>Customer Information:</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstNameInput" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="form-control" id="LastNameInput" required />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*etc...*@
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create.cshtml.cs

```
 public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CustomerManagementSystem.Data.CustomerManagementSystemContext _context;

        [BindProperty]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        
        public CreateModel(CustomerManagementSystem.Data.CustomerManagementSystemContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            //Adding Customer to database
            _context.Customer.Add(Customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("/Customers/RegistrationSuccess");
        }
     }
```

This is the second page, where I display the gathered data in a format that I eventually will find a way to screenshot and save as a jpeg to print out as a badge.
RegistrationSuccess.cshtml

```
@page
@model CustomerManagementSystem.Pages.Customers.RegistrationSuccessModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Success";
}
<br />
<br />
<h3>Registration Complete!</h3>
<h5>Thank you for registering. <br /></h5>

<div class="badgebox" id="badge">
                <div style="text-align:center; float:left; padding:0; vertical-align:top; float:left; background-color:red; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:25px; width:10.05cm">
                    <label>CUSTOMER</label>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left">
                     <img style="margin-left:18px; margin-top:13px; border:1px solid black; width: 3.2cm; height:2.4cm" src="@Model.Customer.Picture" alt="Visitor Picture" />
                    <div style="text-align:left; margin-left:15px; margin-top:9px; line-height:0.8; font-size:13px; padding:5px;">
                        <label>Host:</label><br>
                        <label id="destinationlabel">@Model.Customer.Destination</label><br><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right; margin-top:3px; margin-right:7px; margin-bottom:0px; font-family: Arial; vertical-align:top">
                    <label id="datelabel">@Model.Customer.DateCheckedIn.ToShortDateString()</label>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; line-height:0.8; vertical-align:top">
                    <div style="font-size:45px; margin-top: 30px; line-height:0.1; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0; font-weight: bold;">@Model.Customer.FirstName</div><br />
                    <div style="font-size:45px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0; font-weight: bold;">@Model.Customer.LastName</div>
                    <label id="companynamelabel" style="font-size:18px; margin-left: 20px">@Model.Visitor.CompanyName</label><br>
                    <label id="titlelabel" style="font-size:18px; margin-left:20px">@Model.Visitor.CompanyTitle</label>
                </div>
                <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 10.05cm; background-color: red; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px; text-align: right">
                    <label id="bottomredbar"></label>
                </div>
</div>
```

RegistrationSuccess.cshtml.cs

```
public class RegistrationSuccessModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        private readonly CustomerManagementSystem.Data.CustomerManagementSystemContext _context;

        public RegistrationSuccessModel(CustomerManagementSystem.Data.CustomerManagementSystemContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            return RedirectToPage("/Customers/RegistrationSuccess");
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm having is when I submit the information from the Create page, the data is added to the database, but doesn't pass to the RegistrationSuccess page, so I get the error (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object') when the page tries to redirect to the RegistrationSuccess page. If I add asp-page="RegistrationSuccess" to the form tag in Create.cshtml, then the information passes to the RegistrationSuccess page, but isn't added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo(Page1 form submit data to Page2):

Model:

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
```

Page1.cshtml:

```
<form asp-page="Page2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Page1.cshtml.cs:

```
public class Page1Model : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

Page2.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="firstnamelabel">@Model.Customer.FirstName</label>
    <label id="lastnamelabel">@Model.Customer.LastName</label>
</div>
```

Page2.cshtml.cs:

```
public class Page2Model : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

1.Don't use `asp-page`,`asp-page="Page2"` means the form will post data to Page2 rather than Page1,so this is the reason when you use `asp-page`,data will not be saved,because the handler will not be called.

2.Use RedirectToPage to pass data:

Create.cshtml.cs:

```
...  
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
            {
                //Adding Customer to database
                _context.Customer.Add(Customer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Customers/RegistrationSuccess",Customer);
            }
```

RegistrationSuccess.cshtml:

```
...
public IActionResult OnGet(Customer c)
        {
            Customer=c;
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: This code works; thanks for the help. Unfortunately, however, form with asp-page prevents the information from posting to the customer database (it gets rid of form method=post); any ideas on how to post to the database and send info to page2?

Comment: What do you mean `it gets rid of form method=post`?Do you have any error message?

Comment: On Page1.cshtml for the form tag, I need to have method=post to add the new data to the database; however, when I add asp-page="Page2" so the form tag is  
  <form method=post asp-page="Page2">   , the data shows up on Page2, but isn't added to the database

Comment: How do you add data to database?Can you show your code?Form will only pass data.

Comment: I edited the post to include the relevant code; I appreciate the help